# Custom css box in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm developing a plugin for WordPress and I want to give the users the possibility of add custom css. I saw this option in many plugins and it's going to be very helpful for my clients have this option.

The problem is that, I don't now how to do it. Can you help me? can you explain to me how this can be done? here is a picture of what I want...

[image: example of what i want]

Comment: this manual might help you 
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/

Comment: There is no need for css textbox in your plugins, since WordPress now supports custom css in the Customizer that works really nicely https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/#sections

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the **theme** of a WordPress site controls the entire look of a site, and all loaded plugins. As users have an inherent ability to modify *any* CSS on their WordPress site through the theme itself, there's really no need to give them an additional area where they can modify CSS for a specific plugin.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You only need get the text of your CSS rules textarea, put into a style tag and then append into head tag.

```
var cssRulesFromTextArea = '...';
var customCss = document.createElement('style');
customCss.type = 'text/css';
customCss.innerHTML = cssRulesFromTextArea;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(customCss);
```